# How to search in a list of dictionaries python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm learning python and I found a nice problem where I need to find the highest bidder in data that is entered by user.
I think the easier way was just to create a dictionary and look for the highest bid value such as {"Mark":150, "Peter":160, "Terry":155}, but I though how would it be for have this problem solved in a list of dictionaries, so, since I am curious and I want to learn here is the challenge.

***Challenge:***
*From the following list of dictionaries, find the highest bid.*

```
my_list = [{'name': 'Mark', 'bid': 150},
           {'name': 'Peter', 'bid': 160}, 
           {'name': 'Terry', 'bid': 155}]
```

Your help is much appreciated, I think it would be valuable to understand how to work with list of dictionaries.

here is the code, showing I accomplished what I wanted to achieve on my program.

```
bids = {}
bidding_finished = False

def find_highest_bidder(bidding_record):
  highest_bid = 0
  winner = ""
  # bidding_record = {"Mark": 123, "Terry", "321"}
  for bidder in bidding_record:
    bid_amount = bidding_record[bidder]
    if bid_amount > highest_bid: 
      highest_bid = bid_amount
      winner = bidder
  print(f"The winner is {winner} with a bid of ${highest_bid}")

while not bidding_finished:
  name = input("What is your name?: ")
  price = int(input("What is your bid?: $"))
  bids[name] = price
  should_continue = input("Are there any other bidders? Type 'yes or 'no'.\n")
  if should_continue == "no":
    bidding_finished = True
    find_highest_bidder(bids)
  elif should_continue == "yes":
    clear()
```

So, I really want to learn and understand how to deal with List of dictionaries.

Comment: Can you show what you have already tried? Doesn't matter if it's a brute force algo as well. We can help in improving that. Else this qualifies as a homework question.

Comment: Are you looking for `max` with `key`, like `max(my_list, key=lambda d:d["bid"])`?

Comment: I added my full code there to show is not a homework or whatsoever. I really want to understand in a simple way how to search for the highest bidder when using a list of dictionaries. @RahulBharadwaj
I haven't gone that far to understand what lambda does and understand what your wrote here @Chris  ---> ```max(my_list, key=lambda d:d["bid"])```  :-(

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Chris that is probably the best method to solve your problem. Now since you are a beginner, let me give you an explanation (hopefully, by now you at least know about looping!).

A python dictionary is a collection of `key-value` pairs. So, a typical dictionary looks like:

```py
my_dictionary = {
    "key_1" : "value_1",
    "key_2" : "value_2"
}
```

More about [python-dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp). Now, you can extract all the keys by just passing `my_dictionary.keys()` similarly for values you can do `my_dictionary.values()`. For getting the value of a particular `key` from the dictionary, you can do something like:

```py
print(my_dictionary["key_1"])
>> value_1
```

Based on this explanation, for you a simpler execution would be like:

```py
bid_values = []
for item in my_list:
    bid_values.append(item['bid'])
    
print(bid_values)
[150, 160, 155]
```

Now, python also supports *single line for-loop* and the same can be done. So to keep the matter very simple, you can get the max value as: `print(max(bid_values))`

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much for the response and educating me! yes , I will give it a try with this and check :D   thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mr. Hobo for providing guidance and a quick example. Here is how I ended up implementing it:

```
#We initialize bid_nest as a list. This list will contain the dictionaries
bid_nest = []
people_in_room = True

#We add all dictionaries entered by users manually into bid_nest list.
while people_in_room == True:
  name = input("Enter your name : ")
  bid = int(input("Enter your bid: $"))
  bid_nest.append({"name":name,"bid":bid})
  people = ((input("Anybody else in the room: Yes/No:  ")).lower())[0]
  if people == "y":
    people_in_room = True
    clear()
  else:
    people_in_room = False

#Copy all bids into a list and look for the max value in there.
bid_values = []
for item in bid_nest:
  bid_values.append(item['bid'])

#We compare "bids" from list of dictionaries and "value" max bid and then prints the name of the person. Each "i" value will represent the number of the dictionary inside of the list , example: my_list = [{dict_0},{dict_1},]{dict_2}.......]

value = max(bid_values)
for i in range(0,len(bid_nest)):
  if int(bid_nest[i]["bid"])== max(bid_values):
    person = bid_nest[i]["name"]
    print(f"Person with highest bid of {value} is  {person} ")
```